# How to test Heroku python app locally? ImportError: No module named wsgi

Tags: python, heroku, flask, wsgi

First time using Heroku here. I want to host a python Flask application. Kind of starting to get how things work.
I'd like to test my app locally by using the `heroku local` command, but I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named wsgi

Here are my files:

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn choposcope.wsgi --log-file -
```

myapp.wsgi:

```
from choposcope import app as application
```

Error stack trace:

```
[2016-12-01 18:36:21 +0100] [9916] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
6:36:21 PM web.1 |  [2016-12-01 18:36:21 +0100] [9916] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (9916)
6:36:21 PM web.1 |  [2016-12-01 18:36:21 +0100] [9916] [INFO] Using worker: sync
6:36:21 PM web.1 |  [2016-12-01 18:36:21 +0100] [9919] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9919
6:36:34 PM web.1 |  [2016-12-01 18:36:34 +0100] [9919] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
6:36:34 PM web.1 |  Traceback (most recent call last):
6:36:34 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/Yann/Documents/dev/choposcope/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
6:36:34 PM web.1 |      worker.init_process()
6:36:34 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/Yann/Documents/dev/choposcope/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
6:36:34 PM web.1 |      self.load_wsgi()
6:36:34 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/Yann/Documents/dev/choposcope/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
6:36:34 PM web.1 |      self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
6:36:34 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/Yann/Documents/dev/choposcope/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
6:36:34 PM web.1 |      self.callable = self.load()
6:36:34 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/Yann/Documents/dev/choposcope/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
6:36:34 PM web.1 |      return self.load_wsgiapp()
6:36:34 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/Yann/Documents/dev/choposcope/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
6:36:34 PM web.1 |      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
6:36:34 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/Yann/Documents/dev/choposcope/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
6:36:34 PM web.1 |      __import__(module)
6:36:34 PM web.1 |  ImportError: No module named wsgi
6:36:34 PM web.1 |  [2016-12-01 18:36:34 +0100] [9919] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9919)
6:36:34 PM web.1 |  [2016-12-01 18:36:34 +0100] [9916] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
6:36:34 PM web.1 |  [2016-12-01 18:36:34 +0100] [9916] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  null
6:36:34 PM web.1 Exited with exit code 3
```

Also, I do not know if the wsgi module is supposed to be installed by default with flask. When I try to run `pip install mod_wsgi` in my virtual environment, I get this error:

```
pip install mod_wsgi
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Using cached mod_wsgi-4.5.9.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/_1/bhy3l2kj5l36_859j956y87m0000gn/T/pip-build-h3zlPa/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 284, in <module>
        APR_INCLUDES = get_apr_includes().split()
      File "/private/var/folders/_1/bhy3l2kj5l36_859j956y87m0000gn/T/pip-build-h3zlPa/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 245, in get_apr_includes
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_1/bhy3l2kj5l36_859j956y87m0000gn/T/pip-build-h3zlPa/mod-wsgi/
```

Comment: How did you install heroku?

Comment: Not sure what makes you think you need Apache; Heroku doesn't use it at all and it certainly isn't required in development. But you haven't given *nearly* enough information for us to answer the question. What does your project structure look like? Are you in a virtualenv? What libraries have you installed? What is in your procfile? And, most importantly, what does the *full* error traceback say?

Comment: I added the details you asked for. Everything is in the same folder.

Comment: I installed heroku following this link's instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line you gave, gunicorn is expecting you to have a file called:

```
choposcope/wsgi.py
```

You do not show the structure of how your directory and files are setup, but the error indicates that such a file doesn't exist.

Although there is a way to install mod_wsgi-express on Heroku, I wouldn't recommend it as that mechanism is not actively supported.

If you intend to use gunicorn for local development to match what is used on Heroku, you do not need to install mod_wsgi-express there either, although there is no reason why you can't use mod_wsgi-express for development if you wanted to as mod_wsgi-express (not manual Apache/mod_wsgi configuration) is just as easy for local development as other options available.

Not knowing exactly what file system structure you are using, I am guessing that what you need to do is rename the file `myapp.wsgi` to `wsgi.py`. Then change the `Procfile` to have:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi --log-file -
```

The `wsgi` argument is the Python module name, and thus why the file needs to be called `wsgi.py`. When using gunicorn, it expects the WSGI application entrypoint to be `application` by default. You could perhaps also have gotten away without the `wsgi.py` file and used:

```
web: gunicorn choposcope:app --log-file -
```

As to why `pip install mod_wsgi` failed when you tried to install it locally, that is likely due to being on MacOS X and not having the Xcode developer command line tools installed. That or you have a broken or incomplete Apache httpd installation in HomeBrew.

Comment: Changing the name to wsgi.py did the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to download it, you have to create it.

The contents of the file must be:

```
from yourapplication import app as application
```

For more information see Flask documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/mod_wsgi/#creating-a-wsgi-file

Comment: The error changed, but still needs a wsgi module to import. Where is it supposed to be?
I do not know if it is supposed to be installed by default with flask, but if I try to run pip install mod_wsgi in my virtual environment, it fails. I'll add the error to the post.